# What goes up must come down

Tags: pattern, wordplay

> Roundabout  
>   Power up  
>   Single  
>   Ice cream  
>   Miserable old lady  
>   Danish moneys?  
>   I see dead people  
>   Come together  
>   Easy apple  
>   In the middle  
>   Mine!  
>   Not and  
>   Roundabout

What's the pattern here?

Comment: Are you sure about the cryptic-clues tag?

Comment: Yes. Each line has an answer.

Comment: Alright, cool. Just making sure :p

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The pattern is

> Adding and dropping letters

Roundabout

> O

Power up

> On

Single

> One

Ice cream

> Cone

Miserable old lady

> Crone

Danish money

> Croner, a misspelling of kroner?

I see dead people

> Coroner

Come together

> Corner

Easy apple

> Corer?

In the middle

> Core

Mine!

> Ore

Not and

> Or

Roundabout

> O

Hence the title!

Comment: That's it! Well done!

Comment: Haha thanks. Liked it. Btw is corer a word? Ive only ever heard of it as meaning an apple corer

Comment: Yeah, it's a word, but I think you're right that it only gets used as the apple tool. Croner is definitely not a word, which is why I added the question mark to the clue.